# Tunneling connection to server using another server as "proxy"?

Tags: ssh, proxy, ssh-tunnel

So there are two servers:

- Main server, lets call it `M1`. It's the server every user will need to access somehow.
- Proxy server, lets call it `P1`. It's the server to help some users connect to `M1` through it.

`M1` and `P1` servers have fast (Lan) connection between themselves, so you can access `M1` from `P1` through internal IP. let say this: `10.98.201.15`. Some users that are geographically closer to `M1` can connect directly to `M1`. Users that are geographically very far away can also connect to `M1`, but it suffers heavy latency.

And idea is to let those users connect to `P1`, which is closer to those users and then `P1` would tunnel connection via fast line to `M1`, theoretically reducing latency.

Let say `M1` host is `somemainhost.com` And `P1` is `someproxyhost.com`.
When accessing `somemainhost.com`, you access Odoo server. It is on reverse proxy too, so you don't need to enter `somemainhost.com:8069`.

I read this guide (http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/set-up-ssh-tunneling-on-a-linux-unix-bsd-server-to-bypass-nat/)

And then tried this (From `P1` server):

```
ssh -L 9090:10.98.201.15:8069 myuser@somemainhost.com
```

And after entering this, it asked me to enter password. I did and I just logged in to `M1` and nothing happened. I tried connecting to `M1` with browser, using this:

```
someproxyhost.com:9090
```

But just got connection refused. So I guess I didn't set up any ssh tunneling?

Now how can I make such tunneling connection, so that when user access `someproxyhost.com`, proxy server tunnels connection to `somemainhost.com` and user actually connects to `M1` through `P1`?

**Update**

Here is an example how it should look like:

[image]

Comment: Firstly, you are doing `ssh -L` wrong. It won't show anything, it's not supposed to. Someproxyhost.com:9090 won't work, it's not supposed to. SSH port forwarding operates on localhost. You would need to do `ssh localhost:9090` to achieve anything useful.

Comment: Also, you should probably use Mosh. Mosh is specifically designed as an SSH alternative that works well over high latency and/or unreliable connections: https://mosh.mit.edu/

Comment: @qasdfdsaq But I need to connect to that proxy server (`P1`) somewhat normally as anyone would connect, via that server's external IP. Then that server would pass connection as like that user actually connected to that `M1` server. Is it not possible to achieve this? Also I tried mosh and I could connect to other server like with `ssh` but don't see a way to make such connection I need. Is there a way I don't see?